# Gitlab Runner Failed to register

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab instance with a public IP set up and running. However, trying to add a gitlab-runner fails, because the reverse lookup for the runner does not seem to work as intended. When registering the runner, I can see an incoming POST request with HTTP status 200 on nginx on the gitlab instance

```
1.2.3.4 - - [09/Oct/2021:21:41:51 +0200] "POST /api/v4/runners HTTP/1.1" 200 179 "-" "gitlab-runner 14.3.2 (14-3-stable; go1.13.8; linux/amd64)"
```

but the runner registration fails.

```
 sudo gitlab-runner --debug register --non-interactive --url https://gitlab.example.org/ --registration-token asdasdasdasd --executor shell --tag-list shared --run-untagged=true --locked=false --access-level=not_protected
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=2488 revision=e0218c92 version=14.3.2
Checking runtime mode                               GOOS=linux uid=0
Running in system-mode.                            
                                                   
Dialing: tcp gitlab.example.org:443 ...         
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=LQ_-Gq-k status=200 OK
PANIC: Failed to register the runner. You may be having network problems.
```

The message is a bit misleading...

How to show what happens in gitlab after the connection was made? I mean the HTTP response is officially a 200.

The runner runs behind a NAT and has no public IP, but the gitlab instance has. The route and DNS settings are working to be able to resolve the runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitlab runs behind an Nginx reverse proxy, but the proxy is not controlled by `gitlab-ctl`. Since this was a fresh install, I checked my vhost definition and figured that it may be the case, because the incoming requests to register seemed to be eaten by nginx somehow. `gitlab-ctl tail` did not even log the incoming request to register the runner.

With that assumption, I enabled the nginx shipped with gitlab in `gitlab.rb`

```rb
nginx['enable'] = true
```

and ran `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` just to disable nginx in `gitlab.rb` afterwards

```rb
nginx['enable'] = false
```

and run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` again.

After that procedure, nginx configs are in `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/`. I replaced my vhost definition with `gitlab-http.conf` and adapted it further.

Now it all works as intended. My vhost template was completely outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I use the ddns, so that you need to resolve the domain name by editing the hosts file, in my case is ubuntu:

```
/etc/hosts
```

add the ip address of your gitlab server ip, like this:

```
192.168.2.180  yourgitlab.yourdomain.com
```

then, execute the gitlab-runner register again, it should be successful.

```
sudo gitlab-runner register --url https://<yourgitlab.yourdomain.com> --registration-token <your token>
```